# JComboBox second KeyListener prevents first to get fired

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, keylistener

I'm observing the following behaviour:

adding a new KeyListener to JComboBox and calling e.consume() stops the Default KeyListener from firing its Events.

Here is my example code:

```
final JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(fooList);

final KeyListener fooKeyListener = new KeyAdapter(){
  @Override
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
      System.out.println("VK_DOWN fired");
      e.consume();
    }
  }
};

cb.addKeyListener(fooKeyListener);
contentPanel.add(cb);
```

After this, when I press the Arrow Down Button, I only get "VK_DOWN fired" outputted and the whole Scrolling/Selecting-Mechanism *stops* working.

I would expect, that the default KeyListener, which is responsible for all that scrolling-Stuff gets executed first, so e.consume() shouldn't stop it from working. And by the way, calling `e.consume()` is *the only* way to stop the Scrolling mechanism! Even calling `cb.removeKeyListener(cb.getKeyListeners()[0]);` does *not* stop the Scrolling mechanism from working (which, in my opinion, seems to be very weird!).

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would expect, that the default KeyListener, which is responsible for all that scrolling-Stuff gets executed first,

Actually the order of event firing is not defined and you should never code assuming a specific order. In fact the current default implementation invokes the last listener added first.

> Even calling cb.removeKeyListener(cb.getKeyListeners()[0]); does not stop the Scrolling mechanism from working (which, in my opinion, seems to be very weird!).

Swing was designed to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). Scrolling is enabled by a default Action being mapped to the Down key. You can see all the default mappings by checking out [Key Binding Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/)

> calling e.consume() is the only way to stop the Scrolling mechanism!

You can disable the default `Key Binding` for the Down arrow by using:

```
InputMap im = comboBox.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "none");
```

Comment: When I add two KeyListener, where one of them outputs "1" and the other outputs "2" on keyPressed(), then they get always fired in the exact order in which they have been added to the component. I want to believe, that the default implementation invokes the last listener added first, but that's hardly what I can observe.

It seems that the Key Bindings mechanism gets invoked *after* the KeyListener and only if (e.isConsumed() == false).

Comment: @Hans - Hmm, interesting. I was under the impression that all events where handled by the `EventListenerList` class which I thought was the standard mechanism of how listeners were added to components. If you read the documentation in that class you will see that events are handled in reverse order. I did a quick test by adding ActionListeners and KeyListeners to a JButton. The KeyListeners fired in FIFO order (as you noted) and the ActionListeners fired in LIFO order. So we have inconsistency. Moral of the story is don't rely on order.